Confusion over Terraform docs on provider inheritance
I have a setup as so:
root
    > child a
        > child b
        > child c
        > child d

Up until recently every resource in every module was for the same region in AWS (say eu-west-1), I had a single provider block in the root module:
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

Everything just worked, and the resources were created in the correct region, so can only assume all the children and grandchildren implicitly inherited the default provider, which makes sense according to the docs.
Now module d needs to create a resource in a different region, us-east-1. So what I've done is setup a second provider at root level with an alias:
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us_east_1"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

I then passed this to module child a and then again to d with
in root:
module "child-a" {
  source = "../child-a"
  providers = {
    aws.us_east_1 = aws.us_east_1
  }

in child a:
module "child-d" {
  source = "../child-d"
  providers = {
    aws.us_east_1 = aws.us_east_1
  }

in child d:
required_providers { 
   aws = { 
     source = "hashicorp/aws" version = ">= 4.16" 
     configuration_aliases = [aws.us_east_1] 
   } 
} 

note I am only passing the aliased provider, and this provider is only needed by a resource in child d and not any of the other children.
This all seemed to work, with everything except child d still using the default provider from root, which confused me because it seems to go against what the Terraform docs say here:

Once the providers argument is used in a module block, it overrides all of the default inheritance behavior, so it is necessary to enumerate mappings for all of the required providers. This is to avoid confusion and surprises that may result when mixing both implicit and explicit provider passing.
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/providers

Are the docs wrong? Does it still implicitly inherit the root module's default provider if you only pass through the aliased provider explicitly?

Did you define the aliased provider in the child D module as well?

There are a lot of moving parts here that could impact the behavior, but with the information provided the basic explanation is that the documentation is describing a situation where all provider configs are aliased, and in this usage you have a default provider configuration, and therefore that prevails on resources without an assigned provider alias.

in module d I have:
required_providers {
    aws = {
      source                = "hashicorp/aws"
      version               = ">= 4.16"
      configuration_aliases = [aws.us_east_1]
    }
  }


@Omiron It would be better to edit that into the question than to add as a comment.
